# swift 1.2 update query errors with Parse.com

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have been learning to code for the last few days on xcode with swift 1.1

I just updated to a new version of xcode which includes swift 1.2 and am having a lot of errors.I have solved a few based on other entries in stackoverflow, but am sill having a number of issues.

The biggest problem is that i don't fully understand how to properly wrap and unwrap optionals while querying for objects with a block

This was my original code:

```
 @IBAction func LoadData(){
    NSLog("loading data")
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()
    var findTimelineData : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            for object in objects{
                self.timelineData.insertObject(object, atIndex: 0)
                println("added one post")
            }
        }else{
            NSLog("error")
        }
```

I know that i should be starting my block with

```
(objects, error)
```

and including some let statements, but nothing I've tried has worked. Can someone give me some guidance?

Thank you,
-AVF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
 @IBAction func LoadData(){
    NSLog("loading data")
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()
    var findTimelineData : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects : [AnyObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            for object in objects!{
                self.timelineData.insertObject(object, atIndex: 0)
                println("added one post")
            }
        }else{
            NSLog("error")
        }
```

If the values are optional or not depends on the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock function, if you control click on it you can see how it was expected to be used (also the autocomplete should create it correctly for you)

Comment: Awesome this worked well for me. I still dont understand how objects is declared with a "?" but then iterated with a "!" down in the block.

Comment: Basically when you declare something with ? means "This variable may hold no value (it's nil)" when you use ! it means "I know this value may have no value in some cases but Swift you can trust me it has value here"

Comment: If you use the operator ? in a declaration of a function it means "I will accept nil values to this variable" ! is never use to declare functions. I hope that help